# Multiple parents in Android styles xml

Tags: android, android-layout

When using android styles, one can specify a parent style like:

```
<style name="MyStyle" parent="@style/ParentStyle"></style>
```

Is is possible to specify multiple parents? If so, how?

Comment: I've read that it's not, but I'm pulling that totally out of my ass as I don't remember where or if I'm even remembering correctly. Hope this helps =D

Comment: I don't think so because if both parent styles define the same attribute how would the system know what to use.  You can always try name="MyStyle.Child" parent="@style/OtherParent"  but I doubt it will work.  Let me know if it does lol!

Comment: @schwiz: Repeating attributes isn't valid XML. There would have to be syntax **within** the attribute value to allow this. I don't think that syntax exists.

Answer (score 7):

According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html), the syntax for `parent` attribute value is `@[package:]style/style_to_inherit` (where `package:` is optional) so a reference to just a single style resource is allowed.

Comment: thanks, that answered my question also about whether parent can refer to a theme attribute like parent="?android:textAppearanceButton" .  Apparently it can't.